# Spring Boot health-based load balancing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot for microservices, and I came accross and issue with load balancing.

Spring Actuator adds special `health` and `metrics` endpoint to the apps; with this, some basic information can be acquired from the running instances.

What I would like to do, is to a create a (reverse)proxy (e.g. with Zuul and/or Ribbon?), which creates a centralized load balancer, that selects instances by their health status.

For example, I have the following microservices

- `client`
- `proxy` (<- I would like to implement this)
- `server 1`
- `server 2`

When the client sends an http request to the proxy, the proxy should be able to decide, which of the to server instances has the least load, and forward request to that one.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: It would all depend on what type of load you want to split on. If its purely request-based load, why not just split the traffic 50/50 if the server(s) are all up? Otherwise you could extend the `health` endpoint to accumulate load-over-time, and use that data in your load balancer to decide where to send traffic

Comment: I would like to do the balancing based on the current load factor (e.g. CPU) of the servers, not the number of request (so basically not purely request-based)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a choice on various load-data, you could implement custom `HealthIndicator`s that accumulate some kind of 'load over time' data, use this in your load balancer to decide where to send traffic.

All custom health indicators will be picked up by spring-boot, and invoked on the actuator /health endpoint.

```
@Component
class LoadIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    Health health() {
        def loadData = ... do stuff to gather whatever load
        return Health.up()
                        .withDetail("load", loadData)
                        .build();
    }

}
```

Perhaps you could already use some of spring-boots metrics already, there's multiple endpoints in the actuator. /beans, /trace, /metrics. Should be possible to find that data in your application too.

Comment: Yes, I would like something similar - what I don't know, how to access this kind of load data in the load balanced (I could actually to some REST requests in the balanced to the servers "manually", but maybe Spring does offer some kind of the help with this (e.g.  injected health objects per client?)

Comment: The loadbalancers i've worked with, i have not implemented myself, but typically makes a http request, to check for the status code (2xx, 4xx, 5xx) to determine if a host is healthy or not. If you implement your own, you could probably look at the actual response data to determine if the host is healthy, and what kind of load it is under.

Comment: Yes, that's my plan :-) I just don't know, if Spring has some kind of built in features for accessing the health of the hosts, or is it something, I have to do "manually"

Comment: take a look at the `/metrics` endpoint it returns data like, memory, free memory, uptime, systemload average and so on. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/SystemPublicMetrics.java for example

Comment: You are rigth; this endpoint is much better suited for my needs than health - updated my question (however, I still don't know, how to access this information from the proxy)